# rails アソシエーション先の並べ替えを維持したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
Post has_many Comment

@post = Post.find(xxx)
@post.comments = post.comments.custom_order
@post.comments
```

`@post.comments` で comments がソートされた状態にしたいのですが、どうすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

`has_many` に[scopeを付け](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)られます。

```
has_many :comments, -> { order('created_at DESC') }
```

として

```
post = Post.find(1)
puts post.comments.to_sql
# SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC
```